# How to make my sorting function tail-recursive?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

All these years, I have been doing coding in imperative style but now started learning functional style and facing some hurdles translating a function into tail-recursive.

Tried modifying and adding prints to understand the code but nothing fruitful

```
def sort(compare: (A, A) => Int): MyList[A] = {
    def sortHelper(x: A, xs: MyList[A]): MyList[A] = {
      if (xs.isEmpty) {
        new Cons(x, Empty)
      }
      else if(compare(x, xs.head) < 0)
      {
        new Cons(x, xs)
      }
      else
      {
         new Cons(xs.head, sortHelper(x, xs.tail))
      }
    }

    sortHelper(h, t.sort(compare))
  }
}
```

```
val listOfInts = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, new Cons(4, Empty)
println(listOfInts.sort((x, y) => y - x))
```

This list gets sorted to [4,3,2,1] and the above code is working but dont know how to make it as tail-recursive.

Any guidance will be helpful.

@Nigel - I tried your solution to my current version of the sort and it worked:

```
def anotherSort(isLess: (A, A) => Boolean): MyList[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def sortHelper(workList: MyList[A], sortedList: MyList[A] = Empty): MyList[A] =
    if(workList.isEmpty) sortedList
    else {
      if(sortedList.isEmpty) sortHelper(workList.tail, new Cons(workList.head, Empty))
      else if(isLess(workList.head, sortedList.head)) sortHelper(new Cons(workList.head, new Cons(sortedList.head, workList.tail)), sortedList.tail)
      else sortHelper(workList.tail, new Cons(workList.head, sortedList))
    }

    sortHelper(this)
  }
```

Thanks for making this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation you navigate `->` and then work `<-` which is akin to a `Right Fold`.

If you think of the List as a call stack you have f(f(f(f(...)))) where you are executing the inner most f first.  This is the opposite of tail recursion.

What you want to do is unwrap one layer, create a result and recurse using the rest of the list.

Doing this from left to right, your sortHelper function should probably take the current working version of the list, plus as another argument the sorted version.  You can then recurse pulling one element from the working list and putting it on the sorted list.  If you run into a situation where your current element is less then the head of the sorted list, you should back peddle and put the sorted head back on the working list, and then put the head back on the list as well (because you don't know if you will run into this situation again when you recurse).

That's the wordy version of the answer to give you a chance to try the code yourself.

I have included the code below, don't look if you want to try it yourself:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

sealed trait MyList[+A] extends Product with Serializable {
  val isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: A
  def tail: MyList[A]
  def sort(isLess: (A, A) => Boolean): MyList[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def inner(working: MyList[A], sorted: MyList[A] = Empty): MyList[A] = working match {
      case Empty => sorted
      case Cons(h, t) =>
        if (sorted.isEmpty) inner(t, Cons(h, Empty))
        else if (isLess(h, sorted.head)) inner(Cons(h, Cons(sorted.head, t)), sorted.tail)
        else inner(t, Cons(h, sorted))
    }

    inner(this)
  }
}

case object Empty extends MyList[Nothing] {
  val isEmpty = true
  def head = throw new NotImplementedError("No head on Empty list")
  def tail = throw new NotImplementedError("No tail on Empty list")
}

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A] {
  val isEmpty = false
}

object SortTest extends App {
  val listOfInts: MyList[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Empty))))
  val isLess: (Int, Int) => Boolean = (x, y) => x < y

  println(listOfInts.sort(isLess))
}
```

Just for fun, here it is tweaked to use Scala's List and Ordering typeclass:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.Ordering.Implicits._

object SortTest extends App {
  def sort[A: Ordering](lst: List[A]): List[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def inner(working: List[A], sorted: List[A] = Nil): List[A] = working match {
      case Nil => sorted
      case h :: t =>
        val (w, s) = sorted.headOption.fold((t, h :: Nil)){ sh =>
          if (h < sh) (h :: sh :: t, sorted.tail)
          else (t, h :: sorted)
        }

        inner(w, s)
    }

    inner(lst)
  }

  val listOfInts: List[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil

  println(sort(listOfInts))
}
```